# Creating a dataframe from list of lists: Column Data Repeating for Each Record

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a list of lists that I'm trying to convert into a dataframe. As the title suggests, each record contains the column name and the value. Here's a modified example of what my list looks like:

```
    sample_list =
        [['record',''],
        ['fname','John'],
        ['lname','Smith'],
        ['bdate','1985-06-15'],
        ['record',''],
        ['fname','Mary'],
        ['lname','Smith'],
        ['bdate','1990-03-12'],
                          ...]
```

I'm coming from the VBA world and I'd probably handle something like this with a loop. However, I've been warned to not do that for really large datasets (happens to be case where this conversion is needed). What method should I use to give me the following result:

```
fname | lname | bdate
John  | Smith | 1985-06-15
Mary  | Smith | 1990-03-12
...
```

Any help or pointing in the right direction is very appreciated.

Comment: Do you have access to the column name beforehand? By the way, naming a variable `list` is a bad idea.

Comment: Well, the column names seem to be 100% consistent from record to record in this list. So, in a way I do have the column names. The list name was for example purposes, but I added that edit to the post. -- thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few possible solutions in this style, I settled on one which I think is decent. I know you said the input is rather large, and you were worried about the effects of an explicit loop, so let me know if this fares poorly.

```py
import pandas as pd

raw_data = [['record', ''],
            ['fname', 'John'],
            ['lname', 'Smith'],
            ['bdate', '1985-06-15'],
            ['record', ''],
            ['fname', 'Mary'],
            ['lname', 'Smith'],
            ['bdate', '1990-03-12']]

# generates dictionaries mapping the column name to the value, for each record
rec_dicts = (dict(raw_data[i + 1:i + 4]) for i in range(0, len(raw_data), 4))

df = pd.DataFrame(rec_dicts)
df['bdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['bdate'])

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  fname  lname      bdate
0  John  Smith 1985-06-15
1  Mary  Smith 1990-03-12
```

---

Here is a solution which accounts for missing/different data in records.

```py
import pandas as pd

raw_data = [['record', ''],
            ['fname', 'John'],
            ['lname', 'Smith'],
            ['bdate', '1985-06-15'],
            ['other', 'a value'],
            ['record', ''],
            ['fname', 'Mary'],
            ['lname', 'Smith'],
            ['bdate', '1990-03-12']]

rec_dicts = []
curr_rec = {}

for curr_key, curr_val in raw_data:
    if curr_key == "record":
        rec_dicts.append(curr_rec)
        curr_rec = {}
    else:
        curr_rec[curr_key] = curr_val
rec_dicts.append(curr_rec)

if not rec_dicts[0]:
    rec_dicts = rec_dicts[1:]

print(rec_dicts, end='\n\n')

df = pd.DataFrame(data=rec_dicts)
df['bdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['bdate'])

print(df)
```

Output:

```
[{'fname': 'John', 'lname': 'Smith', 'bdate': '1985-06-15', 'other': 'a value'}, {'fname': 'Mary', 'lname': 'Smith', 'bdate': '1990-03-12'}]

  fname  lname      bdate    other
0  John  Smith 1985-06-15  a value
1  Mary  Smith 1990-03-12      NaN
```

As with the previous method, there are many possible variations. Which one is best will depend on the specifics of your program.

Comment: For clarification, where you've input 4  in the rec_dicts, that is the total record size?

Comment: The data I'm actually working with has 41 columns. I replaced the '4' with a '41' for the dataset I'm working with and when attempting to create the dataframe, I receive this error: ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 as length 76; 2 is required. My guess is that somewhere in the long list, there is a record that has more than 41 columns (or less?). I'll investigate further and update once I know. thank you

Comment: Update: I found all of the inconsistent rows (empty column data) and removed them. 
Cleaning that up gave me consistent 37 columns for every record (confirmed 100% consistent now)
So, I still have the same ValueError, but now the length of 35, 2 is required.

Comment: @ttammountain Yes, 4 is the record size!

Comment: @ttammountain So you don’t need a fix for the inconsistent record sizes? I will likely update the solution to include one anyway, as it might help with whatever is causing the ValueError.

Comment: this worked beautifully! I feel that I need a good python teacher such as yourself... haha
Thank you for your help on this!

Comment: @ttammountain The `ValueError`s are gone?

Comment: Yes, this did the trick! I did include some pieces of code prior to including what you provided to clean up some inconsistencies (ie when an item in a list contains more than just the two values (col data, val data)). All the same, what you provided definitely worked.

Comment: @ttammountain That's great to hear, glad it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

It probably be best to just iterate over the data, but this is a `pandas` solution with `pivot`:

```
(pd.DataFrame(lst)
   .assign(group=lambda x: x[0].eq('record').cumsum())
   .pivot(index='group', columns=0, values=1)
   .drop('record', axis=1)
)
```

output:

```
0           bdate fname  lname
group                         
1      1985-06-15  John  Smith
2      1990-03-12  Mary  Smith
```

Comment: I like this method, however I ran into a KeyError: 1. If I'm not mistaken, I believe it's this piece: .pivot(index='group', columns=0, values=1). Perhaps I'm missing something?